Why is there no signpost?
The following is from Nollywood: From Igbo to English, by Jonathan Haynes

Glamour Girls 1, which came out in 1994, was the first video film made in English. This was an event no less momentous than the appearance of Living in Bondage, and its importance was better understood at the time: it was heralded by radio, television, and billboard advertisements. It opened up a huge new market—a national Nigerian market, in the first place, and also, as an unintended consequence, an international one.
Nollywood’s hegemony across Africa, its deep penetration of the Caribbean, and its inroads among African Americans would be unlikely if its medium were not the most powerful world language. It was not obvious that filmmaking in English would work. At the end of the celluloid filmmaking era, Afolabi Adesanya concluded (after poor returns on his English-language film Vigilante (1988)) that while Nigerian audiences would watch television programs in English, they would not go out and spend their own money to see English-language films.

I have no idea about why there is no signpost like “at the same time” between “… would be unlikely if its medium was not the most powerful world language.” and “It was not obvious that…”
I think that there should be “However”, “But” ,or something like that. The appropriate one is “at the same time” I think. How do you think about this, and what words would you put here?

The only possible answer is 'because the author chose not to'.

You're right to point out that "the most powerful world language" [which I understand to mean "film"] and "it was not not obvious that filmmaking in English would work" seem to go in opposite directions; that places most of the burden on in English.  In speech "in English" could be emphasized. In writing, the two words could be placed in italics. That would be an alternative to a word like "Yet" or "However" or "Though" as connector.

I would probably use "though" along with in English : "... , tne most powerful world language, though it was not obvious that filmmaking in English would work."

I could be wrong to understand that "the most powerful world language" is a figurative use of "language", but calling film a universal language is a cliche: https://www.google.com/search?q=movies+are+the+universal++language

And the word "medium" is used: "if its medium were not the most powerful world language"

There's no particular requirement to include a conjunction in such a sentence. This seems to have nothing to do with English grammar (maybe at a push it would work on Writing SE), but it seems such a trivial complaint, and one that could be made of almost any text, that I assume there's some additional back story you've omitted to tell us.

Question form: Is there. I see no reason to quibble about anything in that paragraph.

Conjunctions connect two clauses within the same sentence. The two sections that you refer to are separated by a full stop: that means that they are both sentences, so no conjunction is required.
Some people start a sentence with a conjunction to create a semantic (not grammatical) link to the previous sentence, but there is no grammatical requirement to do so.

As many comments and the answer have pointed out, these so-called "signposts" are optional. But I think you've also misread the intent of the passage. I can see how it's easy to see a contrast or contradiction: The start of the passage is about the benefits that came from making Nigerian films in English, while the second half is about doubt and resistance. But they both come together to make the overall point of the paragraph: It was an important historic moment, and people at the time felt its importance more than we do today, precisely because there was this disagreement. This film chose to go against prevailing wisdom, and there was lots of talk about that.
